# Error when choosing from random list in python

Tags: python, string, list, random

I am trying to choose a random adjective from a list and then displaying it as a label.

```
from tkinter import*
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("amazing")

    rchoice = ["is smart", " is dumb", " is ugl", " is ugly"]
    random.choice(rchoice)


    def doit():
        text1 = word.get()
        label2 = Label(root, text=text1 +rchoice, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20),  fg="purple").place(x=210, y=350)
        return


    word = StringVar()
    entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=word, width=30)
    entry1.pack
    entry1.place(x=150, y=90)


    heading = Label(root, text="app of truth", font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), fg="brown").pack()
    Button = Button(root, text="buten", width=15, height=3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), fg="blue", bg="lightgreen", command=doit).pack(pady=90)

    root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code it returns this error in the "label2" line in the doit() function: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

I understand that I need to convert the list to a string, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rchoice` is a list, so you can't concatenate the string `text1` with it. You should store the returning value of `random.choice(rchoice)` in a variable and concatenate `text1` with that variable instead:

```
rchoice = ["is smart", " is dumb", " is ugl", " is ugly"]
phrase = random.choice(rchoice)

def doit():
    text1 = word.get()
    label2 = Label(root, text=text1 + phrase, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20),  fg="purple").place(x=210, y=350)
    return
```

Comment: Awesome, got it working. I thought this would be harder.